# How to access extra properties from project build.gradle in modules

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

So I'm trying to setup `Maven Publish` in my library which has several modules in it.

I am following [this](https://proandroiddev.com/android-maven-publish-for-your-libraries-b76ad47677df) tutorial since the whole process is imo not that well documented on the Android Documentation. However, I am stuck at the point *Customizing POM File Generation — Basics*. I added the external info in my **project** `build.gradle` and try to add the publishing information in the **modules** `build.gradle`. When I try to sync Gradle I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':projectname'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot get property 'pomGroupID' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
   > Cannot get property 'pomGroupID' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

The code in my `build.gradle` files looks like this:

Project:

```
buildscript {

    // POM information for publishing the library
    ext {
        pomVersion = '4.23'
        pomGroupID = "com.randomname.stackoverflowquestion"
    }
....
```

Module:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId project.ext.pomGroupID
                artifactId project.name
                version project.ext.pomVersion

                artifact(bundleReleaseAar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on what could be the problem in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was very simple. Only had to change

```
project.ext.pomVersion
```

to

```
project.pomVersion
```

Comment: Another option is to change project into rootProject, i.e. rootProject.ext.pomGroupID